# HTML parsing error

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

But I don't know what's causing it on my page at http://www.jazmyn.com/media.html

I keep getting this message:

> HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before

Comment: What keeps giving you that message? A browser (if so, what and what version) or a HTML validator (if so what/where/URL)?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 8 and its coming no up this page

Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 4.0; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; yie8)
Timestamp: Tue, 1 Sep 2009 23:14:25 UTC

Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://jazmyn.com/media.html

Answer (score 2):

See this IEBlog article: [What Happened to Operation Aborted?](http://web.archive.org/web/20100125023542/http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx)

Which says that in IE7 and earlier, if these conditions applied

> 1. The HTML file is being parsed
> 2. Script is executing
> 3. The executing script attempts to add, or remove an element from an unclosed ancestor in the markup tree (not including the script block's immediate parent element).

the parser would throw an exception, obliterating the page, and in some cases crashing the browser altogether.

IE8 caught the exception, and handled the error in a less catastrophic manner, displaying the error in this question.

The problem was finally fixed properly when IE10 was released which incorporated an HTML5 compliant parser.

Answer (score 1):

The full error you are talking about is “HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)”, which gives you a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917) all about it.