# IE8 - html parsing error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Apologies for posting a question that has been dealt with several times in the past, but I have looked through the answers I could find on stack overflow and still cannot fix it.

My problem is the same as the others have had (such as [HTML parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365134/html-parsing-error)). I am using jQuery and this is causing the error. I have tried fixes such as [this](http://albertech.net/2012/02/fix-for-html-parsing-error-unable-to-modify-the-parent-container-element-before-the-child-in-ie8/), which recommends that I wrap my jQuery in `$(document).ready(function(){  }`, but this does not fix the issue.

I am including a php file just before the body tag of my document which sets the headers as JavaScript, sets up some variables and then requires two .js files (which contain various functions, function calls and event triggers). I have tried wrapping the whole of the JS output in the document ready function but still get the same problem.

I have also tried only using the function around function calls or anything that looks like it tries to access a DOM element before the document is loaded (i.e. function calls to functions that access the DOM elements but no the functions themselves) but this does not work either.

I would like to know (i) is there any reason why wrapping all of my jquery in the document ready function should not fix the problem (as copied below)? and (ii) is there any way to debug what exactly is causing the error?

Thanks!

```
echo '$(document).ready(function() {
'; 

    echo 'var station_report_pref = "' . $station . '";
var dropdowns_choose = "'.get_string('dropdowns_' . $choose_or_all, 'theme_pichincha').'";
var dropdowns_ok = "'.get_string('dropdowns_ok', 'theme_pichincha').'";
var preset_main_dd = false;
var sys_admin = false;
';

    if ($adminrole == 'siteadmin') {
        echo 'var sys_admin = true;
';
    }

    if ($_GET['pagetype'] == "admin-user-editadvanced-create") {
        // This is a create new user page
        echo 'preset_main_dd = true;
';
    }

    require_once 'dropdown.js';
    require_once 'dropdown-reports.js';

echo '
});';
```

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to help you debug your code when you haven't shown us your code...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IE8.
You can download the Cumulative Security update for Internet Explorer KB2360131 to resolve this.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27630 (Windows XP)

OR

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27622 (Windows Vista)